# How can i fix Button on ReactJS Doesn't work on firefox only?

Tags: reactjs, firefox, button, reactive-programming, jquery-source-map

every button in reactjs cannot clickable in firefox

```
<button className="btn btn-default" onClick={ this.onSignIn }>Sign In</button>
<button className="btn btn-default" ><Link to="/signup">Register</Link></button>
```

for onclick this is my function

```
onSignIn() {
  //Grab state and post request to backend
  const {
    signInEmail,
    signInPassword
  } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
  });

  // POST request to backend
  fetch('/api/account/signin', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: signInEmail,
      password: signInPassword,
    }),
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json.success) {
        setInStorage('the_main_app', { token: json.token });
        this.setState({
          signInError: json.message,
          isLoading: false,
          signInEmail,
          signInPassword,
          token: json.token,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          signInError: json.message,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      }
    });

}
```

and for Link i just import

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

in another browser (ex: chrome or safari) the button works, but in firefox when i clicked the button, doesn't do anything. And I get the error:

> source map error.

Comment: What is the source map error that you are getting? What does it say?

Comment: I dont' think you should wrap your `Link` element inside a button element.

Comment: Have you tried open developer tools in Firefox and check for errors? The `setInStorage` method is not visible to us. I guess it saves stuff in localStorage or sessionStorate.That might give error in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing link from within your button. That's what causing the problem, since your button catches the click, but doesn't know what to do with it.

Better to use your action. You should be able to do something like this...

```
import { push } from "react-router-redux";

export const changeUrl = location => dispatch => {
  dispatch(push(location));
};
```